# Add "review later" option instead of irrevocably skipping in Review Queues

Tags: feature-request, review

I usually do reviews on [Sports SE](https://sports.stackexchange.com/) and wish there was an option of **reviewing later** an item instead of **skipping** it irrevocably.

Let's say I'm reviewing close votes queue and there's a question where I have already some idea about my decision but still waiting for some input from the author or other users interacting with this question.

I don't want to **skip**, because I am one of the frequent reviewers in the particular subject and I believe my decision could be valuable. If I skip I won't be able to review this item later.

I don't want to make a decision yet (**Leave Open**, **Close** or **Edit**) because I believe some bits are still missing.

But I also want to be able to review other questions while putting this question in the end of the queue (or somewhere closer for large communities). Currently though, the review queue won't show me another item until I make a decision about this question.

Wouldn't it be useful? Is it doable?

Comment: You can find a review that you skipped if you go to the history tab in the review queue and check the "show skipped reviews" checkbox on the bottom right. I do agree though that that's not always practical since it isn't always easy to find a specific review, especially not on larger sites like Stack Overflow where you sometimes skip a lot of reviews in a short time.

Comment: You can just click the review tab again and it will reload the page. It's not a guarantee you'll get a new task, but you usually do - depends how many tasks there are in the queue. You're not locked to looking at only that one before you can see something else. I do this all the time to temporarily skip a review for a moment. But as noted above, skipping doesn't lock you out of reviewing it either, and you can track it down again.

Comment: "If I skip I won't be able to review this item later." Is that really the case? I think that skipping only hides it temporarily. If I come back a while later (the next day, perhaps), skipped review items get shown again.